# drupal 8 and link to file

Tags: file, drupal, hyperlink, reference

I installed drupal 8.2.7, no extra plugins or themes.
I have added in the "base page" (structure / type) a field (file1) to upload files.

If I add a new page (drupal / node / add / page) and also load a file in file1 (test.txt), the new page displays me the link to the file.

Then I add a new field called file2 as entity reference (file type).
If I add a new page (drupal / node / add / page) and put in file2 a reference to the test.txt, I see the new page, but with only the label name of the file, not its link

---

you can test the error on:

https://r20kx.ply.st/node/1

https://r20kx.ply.st/node/2

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the fields of the content type and from **Manage display** tab change the **Format** settings for the field *file2* to **URL to file**. Check this screen: http://prnt.sc/epnh4n

Comment: hi, 
i have only
<option value="entity_reference_entity_view">Rendered entity</option>
<option value="entity_reference_entity_id">Entity ID</option>
<option value="entity_reference_label" selected="selected">Label</option><option value="hidden">- Hidden -</option> 


The field file2 is filed type "Entity reference", no "File". 
Then with file2 i want choose a previously uploaded file, do not load another file from pc.

Comment: Did you enabled **File** module ? What Drupal version are you running ?

Comment: File module is enabled, version drupal 8.2.7 (new and clean).
Added in /admin/people/permissions grant to ANONYMOUS USER, AUTHENTICATED USER, ADMINISTRATOR , too

Comment: try creating a new D8 instance here https://simplytest.me/ and give me the link to the instance so I can check the your configuration. good luck

Comment: https://dcfov.ply.st      
https://dcfov.ply.st/node/2             
https://dcfov.ply.st/node/1

Comment: No help on this issue ?

Comment: no help ??

you can test the error on:

https://r20kx.ply.st/node/1 https://r20kx.ply.st/node/2